# Failure to insert record into MySQL database (online) using html form and php, no error messages

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm very new to coding in MySQL and am stuck on my very first project. I'm really sorry in advance if this turns out to be a pretty basic question but I've been scouring docs, tutorials and stackoverflow for days without finding an answer that solved my issue. So here I go.

I'm trying to insert data into a MySQL database that I put online through my hosting company (I run a blog). The insert is supposed to work though an html form and a php script, both of which I uploaded through FTP. The form does show up [here](https://www.hydrologyblogger.com/htdocs/adaptation_capacity.html) and it does give me the response "New record inserted successfully" but no new record appears in the database.

I originally wrote the script to be used on a local database and it worked just fine - I had to move it online because due to COVID-19 my colleagues and I, who are supposed to enter data, are stuck in different places.

I know it's probably an error that just doesn't show up in the form of an error message, so I tried to retrace it. Trying to test for a series of errors, I scaled back the code and created a very simple test table in the database: 
[screenshot of the test database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwqfC.png)

using this code:

html form:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Very basic test to see if db is working</h1>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php code :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("xx", "xx", "xx", "xx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO test (fname, lname)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

I know that it's vulnerable to SQL injection and everything, but I just wanted to see if it very, very basically works. (Spoiler alert: it doesn't - it just gives me a blank page.)

I would be really grateful for any pointers to solutions, or just what else I could check next. I already wrote to my hosting company to ask if there is a general issue with external access, but their customer support is not available due to the coronavirus.

So I would be incredibly grateful for some help. :)

Thanks already in advance!

For reference's sake, here is my actual code (which works on localhost, but fails to insert into the online database):

[Link to online form](https://www.hydrologyblogger.com/htdocs/adaptation_capacity.html)

```
html code: 

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Adaptation Capacity </title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form action="adaptation_capacity_insert.php" method="POST">
      <table>

    <tr>
     <td>Adaptation ID :</td>
     <td><input type="number" name="adaptation_ID" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>What are their strategies to avoid losses due to floods?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="strategies_losses_flood" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>What are their strategies to avoid losses due to droughts?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="strategies_losses_drought" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Do they think that Prek rehabilitation provides an opportunity to decrease flood risk?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="prek_rehab_decrease_floods" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Do they think that Prek rehabilitation provides an opportunity to decrease drought risk?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="prek_rehab_decrease_droughts" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Have they changed crop varieties in the past 5 years?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="variety_change_past" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Are they planning to change crop varieties in the future?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="variety_change_future" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Are they planning to make agricultural investments in the future?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="agri_investments_future" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Were they impacted by the short duration of the flood last year?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="short_duration_last_flood" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Were they impacted by the late arrival of the flood last year?</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="late_arrival_last_flood" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Additional notes on adaptation capacity:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="adaptation_capacity_notes" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td>Interview ID :</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="interview_ID" required></td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
   </tr>

  </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

php code:

```
    <?php
    $adaptation_ID = $_POST['adaptation_ID'];
    $strategies_losses_flood = $_POST['strategies_losses_flood'];
    $strategies_losses_drought = $_POST['strategies_losses_drought'];
    $prek_rehab_decrease_floods = $_POST['prek_rehab_decrease_floods'];
    $prek_rehab_decrease_droughts = $_POST['prek_rehab_decrease_droughts'];
    $variety_change_past = $_POST['variety_change_past'];
    $variety_change_future = $_POST['variety_change_future'];
    $agri_investments_future = $_POST['agri_investments_future'];
    $short_duration_last_flood = $_POST['short_duration_last_flood'];
    $late_arrival_last_flood = $_POST['late_arrival_last_flood'];
    $adaptation_capacity_notes = $_POST['adaptation_capacity_notes'];
    $interview_ID = $_POST['interview_ID'];


    if
        (!empty($adaptation_ID) || !empty($strategies_losses_flood) || !empty($strategies_losses_drought) || !empty($prek_rehab_decrease_floods)
        || !empty($prek_rehab_decrease_droughts)|| !empty($variety_change_past) || !empty($variety_change_future) || !empty($agri_investments_future)
        || !empty($short_duration_last_flood) || !empty($late_arrival_last_flood) || !empty($adaptation_capacity_notes) || !empty($interview_ID)
        )

          {   $host = "xx";
              $dbUsername = "xx";
              $dbPassword = "xx";
              $dbname = "xx";

              //create connection
              $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
              if (mysqli_connect_error())
                  {
                   die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
                  }

              else
                  {
                   $SELECT = "SELECT adaptation_ID From adaptation_capacity Where adaptation_ID = ? Limit 1";
                   $INSERT = "INSERT Into adaptation_capacity (adaptation_ID, strategies_losses_flood, strategies_losses_drought, prek_rehab_decrease_floods, prek_rehab_decrease_droughts, variety_change_past, variety_change_future, agri_investments_future,
                                                               short_duration_last_flood, late_arrival_last_flood, adaptation_capacity_notes, interview_ID)
                                                             values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                   //Prepare statement
                   $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
                   $stmt->bind_param("i", $adaptation_ID);
                   $stmt->execute();
                   $stmt->bind_result($adaptation_ID);
                   $stmt->store_result();
                   $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

                   if ($rnum==0)
                       {
                        $stmt->close();
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
                        $stmt->bind_param("isssssssssss", $adaptation_ID, $strategies_losses_flood, $strategies_losses_drought, $prek_rehab_decrease_floods,
                                                          $prek_rehab_decrease_droughts, $variety_change_past, $variety_change_future, $agri_investments_future,
                                                          $short_duration_last_flood, $late_arrival_last_flood, $adaptation_capacity_notes, $interview_ID);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        echo "New record inserted sucessfully";
                       }
                   else
                       {
                        echo "This adaptation ID has been used already ";
                       }
                   $stmt->close();
                   $conn->close();
                  }
    } else {
     echo "All fields are required";
     die();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Add some error handling for your queries https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and you might get a bit more information. Right now, you're not actually checking if the insert was successful or not.

Comment: Also, if you run your "test code" on PHP 7+, you can't use `mysql_*` since that API was completely removed in PHP 7. Have you checked the web servers error log? Also make sure that you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` while you develop so all errors gets properly logged etc. This can also be set in php.ini.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wow thanks for your quick reply! I'll give that a try right away!